# Can iphone app pick up text message being sent?

Tags: ios, iphone

I’m designing an iphone app that’s based on the following functionality. I know it’s a general question, but if this can’t be done, then app can’t move forward.

Lets say I have an iphone classifieds ads app. I contact the seller by  pressing the phone number and waiting for the [default iphone popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILNky.jpg) that *isn’t* part of the classifieds app. I type the text and click *Send* to send the text message. A regular txt message was sent.

Generally speaking, can an app store the phone number and the message being sent through the iphone/android device?

Comment: You wouldn't get that popup in your app. You can present the `MFMessageComposeViewController` in your app with a preset message text, but the user can change the text before the message is sent and your app does not get access got the message that was sent.

Comment: Thanks. Would I get access to the phone number?

Comment: Well, presumably your app knows the phone number since you are getting it from your database in order to present the message composing view. Of course, the user can change the number to a different number and you won't know if they did that or what number they changed it to